# Multiple Foreach loops in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, forum

Hello im making a forum and i pull data out with fetchAll() func

im calling functions like this

```
$forum_name = $forum->get_forum_name();
$cat_list = $forum->get_category();
```

Now can i use it like this

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1">
<?php 

foreach ($forum_name as $fn) 
{
    echo '<tr><th>' . $fn['forum_name'] . '</th><th>Topics</th><th>Posts</th><th>Latest post</th></tr>';

    foreach ($cat_list as $cl) 
    {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $cl['cat_name'] . '</td></tr>';
    }

} 

?>
</table>
```

Here is the PHP code that is getting called above:

```
<?php

class Forum
{

protected $db;

function __construct(PDO $db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}

// Get forum name title
public function get_forum_name()
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

// FORUM CATEGORIES
// add forum category
public function add_category($cat_name, $cat_desc)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_cat (cat_name, cat_desc) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $query->bindValue(1, $cat_name);
    $query->bindValue(2, $cat_desc);

    $query->execute();
}

// list all forum categories
public function get_category()
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_cat");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

}


?>
```

This doesn't give me any errors. just asking if this will slow the script and if its bad practice to use it like this.

Comment: We can't see in `get_forumn_name` or `get_category`, but there's nothing wrong with using loops in PHP.

Comment: As opposed to what approach? This is likely the last thing you need to be worrying about optimizing.

Comment: the only thing i see a problem with is that if those values are coming straight from the database and the client, you may be victim of [script injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) at some point.

Comment: Since `$cat_list` doesn't change between iterations of `$forum_name`, you could compute the `$cat_list` rows once, and then you wouldn't have to iterate them each time. However, I suspect that your `$cat_list` will end up changing eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Using two nested for loops to generate tables based on those values is relatively inexpensive; the overhead is almost non-existent (assuming this is how you need to get and represent your data).

If `$forum_name` and `$cat_list` get quite large, you might see some latency, but there are not many ways to optimize this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this data , then you need this data,  its not slow or bad practice to use nested loops.

Answer (score -2):

i use class for this like this

```
<?php

class Forum
{

protected $db;

function __construct(PDO $db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}

// Get forum name title
public function get_forum_name()
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

// FORUM CATEGORIES
// add forum category
public function add_category($cat_name, $cat_desc)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_cat (cat_name, cat_desc) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $query->bindValue(1, $cat_name);
    $query->bindValue(2, $cat_desc);

    $query->execute();
}

// list all forum categories
public function get_category()
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_cat");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

}


?>
```

Comment: So, anytime you want the forum name, you make a query? What if that's more than once per request?

Comment: no i just use it like this $example = $forum->get_forum_name(); i have output like this on pic http://prntscr.com/2zzayi

Comment: Right. That will query the database everytime you call it. LOL. Do you even understand your own script? In fact, it will get every field and every row in the `forum` table...

Comment: OK before you make critics look at database structure http://prntscr.com/2zzd3x i know for what i need what and where and how to use it. Btw this is only beggining of making forum its not finished :)

Comment: So, not only are you suggesting the asker use a script that you do not understand. You're also suggesting that he use a script that is incomplete. This has nothing to do with the asker's question.

Comment: No i posted function because of this guy "
 
the only thing i see a problem with is that if those values are coming straight from the database and the client, you may be victim of script injection at some point. –  13ruce1337" and i get my answer I CAN USE MULTIPLE FOREACH ty all for replys #CLOSE TOPIC.

Comment: You have no idea if his script is vulnerable to script injection. You should delete this post. If anything, you should post a pastebin of your script as a comment. This surely isn't an answer.